# Do trivial homology groups imply contractibility of a compact polyhedron?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Is it true that a compact polyhedron X with trivial homology groups (except $H_{0}(X)$ of course) is necessarily contractible? If yes, what is the approach in proving it? If not, do you see a counter-example?

Comment: I think you at least want to specify that $X$ is connected, or else you could take, say, two points.

Comment: The Poincare homology sphere is a counter-example which is a manifold.  It's also called the Poincare Dodecahedral Space.  There's a Wikipedia page for it.

Comment: @Qiaochu: or use reduced homology groups in the formulation of the question instead of homology.

Comment: @Ryan: But... Doesn't a homology $3$-sphere have $H_{3} \cong \mathbb{Z}$ by definition?

Comment: @Ryan: In other words: what was wrong with Mariano's now deleted answer along the lines: If $X$ is connected and *simply connected* then it follows from Hurewicz and Whitehead that the inclusion of any point is a homotopy equivalence. What am I missing?

Comment: @Theo: I don't understand the relationship between your two comments. The Poincare dodecahedral space is not simply connected (but its fundamental group does have trivial abelianization).

Comment: @Qiaochu: I'm sorry, I didn't make myself clear. I agree with what you say, but I don't understand how Ryan's example should be a counterexample to the question  because it has $H_3 = \mathbb{Z}$. Mariano's argument missed the assumption "simply connected" but otherwise it seemed fine to me (I was typing up the exact same thing and got immensely confused). I made the bold assumption that Mariano's deletion was a reaction to Ryans comment and I guess that's what "in other words" was referring to.

Comment: Well, you could take the mapping cone of a homology isomorphism $f:PHS\rightarrow S^3$.  Maybe that doesn't fit what's meant by "polyhedron" here, though.

Comment: @Theo: ah, right.  I forgot about $H_3$.  I'll give a proper example as an answer, if someone else doesn't beat me to it.

Comment: @Ryan: Thanks! Now I'm happy again :)

Comment: Thank you all. You have been of much help. Now I have a counter-example and a proof (for spaces with trivial $\pi_{1}$)!

And indeed, I forgot to mention $X$ was at least path-connected.

Comment: @Liudas: please do not use answers to make comments.

Comment: @Theo, I deleted the answer because I was sure (hah!) that I did not need the simply connectedness but could not think of a reason... Of course, I did need it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To sum up the comments: when Poincaré worked on the beginnings of algebraic topology, he originally thought that a space with trivial homology groups must be contractible. (More precisely, he thought that having the homology group of a 3-sphere implies being a 3-sphere.) However, he soon found a counterexample, the [Poincaré homology sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_conjecture#Poincar.C3.A9.27s_question), which led him to the construction of the *fundamental group*.

When taking the fundamental group into account, the statement is indeed true: if a space has trivial fundamental group and trivial higher homology groups, then it must be contractible. This is a consequence of [Whitehead's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_theorem) and the [Hurewicz map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurewicz_theorem).

Comment: I don't understand how the first two sentences are related.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: If I were to conjecture that homology is a complete invariant, then this would imply both sentences. As to Poincaré's thinking, I am only aware of evidence that backs up the sentence in parentheses, however.

Answer (score 17):

The 2-skeleton of the Poincare homology sphere, also describable as the [presentation complex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_complex) of the [binary icosahedral group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_icosahedral_group), provides a counterexample to your original question.  The fundamental group is of order 120 and is perfect, which implies that that $H_1$ is trivial.  You can check from the group presentation $ <s,t | s^{-3}(st)^2, t^{-5}(st)^2> $ that the second homology group is trivial as well.

Comment: Very nice.   This is the example I should have given!

Answer (score 3):

*(This is the deleted answer the comments refer to; it was missing the hypothesis about simple-connectedness)*

Using the [Hurewicz theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurewicz_theorem), you deduce at once that such a polyhedron [*Edit*: if it is simply connected] has trivial homotopy groups, so that it is weakly homotopy equivalent to a point. Since it is a CW-complex, then [Whitehead's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_theorem) tells you that the polyhedron is in fact contractible.